# Display Inventory Quantity under swatches

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to display the inventory quantity of configurable product under the configurable swatches,

I'm getting the quantity but i'm bit confused about the loop.

[image]

I'm using below method to display the inventory stock details

```
foreach ($_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getUsedProducts ( null, $_product) as $simple) {
    $stock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($simple)->getQty();
    echo  $stock;
    echo '<br/>';
}
```

**Replaced**

> foreach ($_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getUsedProducts ( null,
>   $_product) as $simple)

**With**

> foreach ($_option as $simple):

I'm also including my **swatches.phtml** code here

```
<?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE_AFL.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magento.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magento.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    design
 * @package     rwd_default
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2006-2014 X.commerce, Inc. (http://www.magento.com)
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php  Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 */
?>
<?php
$_product    = $this->getProduct();
$_attribute = $this->getAttributeObj();
$_jsonConfig = $this->getJsonConfig();
$_config = json_decode($_jsonConfig);

$_swatchInnerWidth = $this->getSwatchInnerWidth();
$_swatchInnerHeight = $this->getSwatchInnerHeight();
$_swatchOuterWidth = $this->getSwatchOuterWidth();
$_swatchOuterHeight = $this->getSwatchOuterHeight();

$_attr = $_attribute->getProductAttribute();
$_attrCode = $_attr->getAttributeCode();
$_id = $_attribute->getAttributeId();

$_swatchArray = $_config->attributes->$_id;
?>

<dt class="swatch-attr">
    <label id="<?php echo $_attrCode ?>_label" class="required">
        <em>*</em><?php echo $_attribute->getLabel() ?>:
        <span id="select_label_<?php echo $_attrCode ?>" class="select-label"></span>
    </label>
</dt>

<dd class="clearfix swatch-attr<?php if ($_attribute->decoratedIsLast) echo ' last'; ?>">
    <div class="input-box">
     <select style="display: none;" name="super_attribute[<?php echo $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>]" id="attribute<?php echo $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>" class="required-entry super-attribute-select no-display swatch-select">
            <option><?php echo $this->__('Choose an Option...') ?></option>
        </select>


<!-- Color -->

        <?php if (!$_attribute->decoratedIsLast): ?>
             <ul id="configurable_swatch_<?php echo $_attrCode ?>" class="product-colors-list custom-radio-list configurable-swatch-list clearfix">
            <?php foreach ($_swatchArray->options as $_option): ?>
                <?php
                $_optionCode = Mage::helper('configurableswatches')->getHyphenatedString($_option->label);
                $_swatchUrl = Mage::helper('configurableswatches/productimg')->getSwatchUrl($_product, $_option->label, $_swatchInnerWidth, $_swatchInnerHeight, $_swatchType);
                $_hasImage = !empty($_swatchUrl);
                $_liClass = '';
                $_aClass = 'swatch-link swatch-link-' . $_attribute->getAttributeId();?>
                <?php if ($_hasImage):
                    $_liClass .= $_swatchType == 'media' ? ' is-media' : '';
                    $_aClass .= ' has-image'; ?>
                <?php elseif (strlen($_option->label) > 3):
                    $_liClass .= ' wide-swatch'; ?>

                <?php endif?>
                <li class="productcolor inline-element custom-radio-item option-<?php echo $_optionCode; ?><?php echo $_liClass; ?>" id="option<?php echo $_option->id; ?>">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" name="<?php echo $_optionCode; ?>" id="swatch<?php echo $_option->id; ?>" class="<?php echo $_aClass ?>" title="<?php echo $_option->label; ?>"
                       style="border: none; height: <?php echo $_swatchOuterHeight ?>px; <?php if (!$_hasImage): ?>min-<?php endif; ?>width: <?php echo $_swatchOuterWidth ?>px;">

                <span class="product-option-color-wrapper">
                <?php if ($_hasImage): ?>
                      <span class="product-option-color"><img style="position: inherit;" src="<?php echo $_swatchUrl; ?>" class="full-width-img" alt="<?php echo $_option->label; ?>" /></span>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <span class="product-option-color"><img style="position: inherit;" src="<?php echo $_option->label; ?>" class="full-width-img" alt="<?php echo $_option->label; ?>" /></span>
                <?php endif; ?>
                </span>
                <span class="product-option-color-title"><?php echo $_option->label; ?></span>
                <span class="x">X</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
             </ul>
        <?php endif; ?>

<!-- Size -->

            <?php if ($_attribute->decoratedIsLast):?>
                <ul id="configurable_swatch_<?php echo $_attrCode ?>" class="product-options-list custom-radio-list configurable-swatch-list clearfix">
                <?php foreach ($_swatchArray->options as $_option): ?>
                    <?php foreach ($_option as $simple): ?>
                        <?php $simple--; ?>
                        <?php /*var_dump($_product,$_option)*/?>
                <?php $_optionCode = Mage::helper('configurableswatches')->getHyphenatedString($_option->label);
                    $_swatchUrl = Mage::helper('configurableswatches/productimg')->getSwatchUrl($_product, $_option->label, $_swatchInnerWidth, $_swatchInnerHeight, $_swatchType);
                    $_hasImage = !empty($_swatchUrl);
                    $_liClass = '';
                    $_aClass = 'swatch-link swatch-link-' . $_attribute->getAttributeId(); ?>
               <?php  if ($_hasImage) :?>
                    <?php $_liClass .= $_swatchType == 'media' ? ' is-media' : '';
                    $_aClass .= ' has-image'; ?>
                    <?php elseif (strlen($_option->label) > 3):?>
                   <?php  $_liClass .= ' wide-swatch'; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <li class="productsize product-option custom-radio-item option-<?php echo $_optionCode; ?><?php echo $_liClass; ?>"
                            id="option<?php echo $_option->id; ?>">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0)" name="<?php echo $_optionCode; ?>"
                           id="swatch<?php echo $_option->id; ?>" class="<?php echo $_aClass ?>"
                           title="<?php echo $_option->label; ?>"
                           style="border: none; height: <?php echo $_swatchOuterHeight ?>px; <?php if (!$_hasImage): ?>min-<?php endif; ?>width: <?php echo $_swatchOuterWidth ?>px;">
                          <span class="product-option-size"><?php echo $_option->label; ?></span>

                            <?php $stock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($simple)->getQty();
                            echo  round($stock); ?>

                            <span class="product-option-stock"><?php echo $this->__('In stock') ?></span>




                        </a>

                    </li>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                </ul>
            <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
</dd>
```